# C2039 - FUNCTION Is not a member of CLASS

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm experimenting a little bit with templated classes and I have found this error:

```
Error   C2039   'getName': is not a member of 'Person<T>
```

This is my class structure:

```
struct professor
{
    static const char name[];
    static const age = 50;
};

struct student
{
    static const char name[];
    static const age = 21;
};

const char professor::name[] = "Jules";
const char student::name[] = "Michael";


// Please make the Person template class here.

template <class T>
class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    char[] getName();

private:
    T & m_Person;
};

template<class T>
Person<T>::Person()
{
    m_Person= T;
}

template<class T> 
char* Person<T>::getName()
{
    return m_Person.name;
}
```

Do you know what is failing?

In fact I don't know if the class definition etc are correct because I'm quite new with the templated classes so If you see any other error It would be great If you warn me.

THank you, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Lots of oddities in there. For example, what's an `age`? Anyway, `char* Person<T>::getName()` vs `char[] getName();`. See the difference in return types between the two? Now that I think about it, I'm not sure you can return `char[]`. Hack test: https://ideone.com/WWwI7G . Compiler hates it. Return `char *` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix compilation errors from first to last. `char[]` is not a valid return type, the function definition for `getName()` fails to compile that's why you get the error.

You are also missing the type specifier for the `age` member variables as C++ does not support default int.

---

Your code is a little confusing, I think you want something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct professor
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

struct student
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

template <class T>
class Person
{
public:
    Person(const T& person) : m_Person(person) {}

    std::string getName()
    {
        return m_Person.name;
    }

private:
    T m_Person;
};

int main() {
    student s{"Michael", 21};    
    Person<student> p(s);
    std::cout << p.getName();    
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use a class with only static members as a template parameter, you don't need to store an instance:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    static const int x = 42;
};

template <typename T>
struct A {
    int getValue() {
        return T::x;
    }
};

int main() {
    A<S> a;
    std::cout << a.getValue();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler should also howl over `m_Person= T;`. That's assigning a type to a variable.

Comment: I missed that, it probably will when you instantiate a `Person`.

Comment: I mark your answer as correct. Thank you!

Yep, I have an error now on 'm_Person = T'. 

The error is:  references must be initialized. Sorry if they are really noob questions. I'm just starting with C++

Comment: Normally, you can't have a null reference so you have to initialize it in the constructor initializer list, but I don't think a reference is needed here. Added some code to the answer.